# Adding a for loop to include all columns in my data set

Tags: r, loops

How can i manipulate this code using perhaps a for-loop?

```
tbl1 <- table(Column1Name)

cbind(tbl1,prop.table(tbl1))
```

This code works well for one column but there is over 100 columns in the 
data set that I am working with at the moment so it is very inefficient for me 
to repeat this and change the column name etc. each time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
tbl1 <- table(Column1Name)

cbind(tbl1,prop.table(tbl1))
```

gives the count and percentage of each of the factors in each variable and I want to do this 
for all of my variables using a general code for all.

Comment: Please include a [**small reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some data:

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,1000,replace=TRUE),nrow=100))
```

Sounds like you want something like:

```
lapply(data,FUN=function(x) rbind(table(x),prop.table(table(x))))
```

Or maybe:

```
t(sapply(data,FUN=function(x) cbind(table(x),prop.table(table(x)))))
```

Comment: lapply(data,FUN=function(x) rbind(table(x),prop.table(table(x)))) worked perfectly! Thanks a million :)